# Json with datatable

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, datatables

I need some help with this, i have reviewed the datatable api and I am not getting something right.

Jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#dblist').on('change', function () {

    var selected = $("select option:selected").text();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/php/connect/searchtablequery.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { UserLogin: selected },
        success: function (data) {
            tablefill(data)
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, err) { console.log(xhr, status, err); }
    });

});

function tablefill(data) {

    $('#table_id').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bDestroy": true,
        "sAjaxSource": data,
        "sAjaxDataProp": "data.inner",
        "aoColumns": [
            { "mDataProp": "calldate" },
            { "mDataProp": "clid" },
            { "mDataProp": "src" },
            { "mDataProp": "dst" },
            { "mDataProp": "dcontext"}],
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "sDom": '<"H"Tfr>t<"F"ip>',
        "oTableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "/DataTables/extras/TableTools/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
            "aButtons": [
                "copy", "csv", "xls", "pdf",
                {
                    "sExtends": "collection",
                    "sButtonText": "Save",
                    "aButtons": ["csv", "xls", "pdf"]
                }
            ]
        }
    });
};
```

});

The JSON returning is

```
{
    "0": {
        "calldate": "2013-08-14 11:41:28",
        "clid": "\"name name\" <1002>",
        "src": "1002",
        "dst": "8834404",
        "dcontext": "from-internal",
        "channel": "SIP\/1002-00000000",
        "dstchannel": "IAX2\/voipms-6749",
        "lastapp": "Dial",
        "lastdata": "IAX2\/voipms\/14798834404,300,",
        "duration": "7",
        "billsec": "0",
        "disposition": "NO ANSWER",
        "amaflags": "3",
        "accountcode": "",
        "uniqueid": "1376498488.1",
        "userfield": "",
        "did": "",
        "recordingfile": "",
        "cnum": "",
        "cnam": "",
        "outbound_cnum": "",
        "outbound_cnam": "",
        "dst_cnam": ""
    },"1": {
        "calldate": "2013-08-14 11:42:55",
        "clid": "\"name name\" <1002>",
        "src": "1002",
        "dst": "9187755592",
        "dcontext": "from-internal",
        "channel": "SIP\/1002-00000001",
        "dstchannel": "IAX2\/voipms-121",
        "lastapp": "Dial",
        "lastdata": "IAX2\/voipms\/19187755592,300,",
        "duration": "494",
        "billsec": "485",
        "disposition": "ANSWERED",
        "amaflags": "3",
        "accountcode": "",
        "uniqueid": "1376498575.3",
        "userfield": "",
        "did": "",
        "recordingfile": "",
        "cnum": "",
        "cnam": "",
        "outbound_cnum": "",
        "outbound_cnam": "",
        "dst_cnam": ""
    },
```

Comment: ... and? What did you expect instead?

Comment: I cant get information into my datatable.

Comment: The returned json is not an array of objects, that may be causing some problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing:

```
"sAjaxSource": data,
```

To this:

```
"sAjaxSource": '/php/connect/searchtablequery.php',
```

Try also adding:

```
"bServerSide": true,
```

**Edit 1:**

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "sAjaxSource": "http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/dataTables/json.php"
  } );
} )
```

Ref. http://datatables.net/usage/options

**Edit 2:**

As shown in my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/HEDvf/667/ your JSON is different from mine.  I don't know if it makes a difference, but I would try changing it.  Here is mine:

```
{
    "calldate": "2013-08-14 11:41:28",
    "clid": "\"name name\" <1002>",
    "src": "1002",
    "dst": "8834404",
    "dcontext": "from-internal",
    "channel": "SIP\/1002-00000000",
    "dstchannel": "IAX2\/voipms-6749",
    "lastapp": "Dial",
    "lastdata": "IAX2\/voipms\/14798834404,300,",
    "duration": "7",
    "billsec": "0",
    "disposition": "NO ANSWER",
    "amaflags": "3",
    "accountcode": "",
    "uniqueid": "1376498488.1",
    "userfield": "",
    "did": "",
    "recordingfile": "",
    "cnum": "",
    "cnam": "",
    "outbound_cnum": "",
    "outbound_cnam": "",
    "dst_cnam": ""
},{
    "calldate": "2013-08-14 11:42:55",
    "clid": "\"name name\" <1002>",
    "src": "1002",
    "dst": "9187755592",
    "dcontext": "from-internal",
    "channel": "SIP\/1002-00000001",
    "dstchannel": "IAX2\/voipms-121",
    "lastapp": "Dial",
    "lastdata": "IAX2\/voipms\/19187755592,300,",
    "duration": "494",
    "billsec": "485",
    "disposition": "ANSWERED",
    "amaflags": "3",
    "accountcode": "",
    "uniqueid": "1376498575.3",
    "userfield": "",
    "did": "",
    "recordingfile": "",
    "cnum": "",
    "cnam": "",
    "outbound_cnum": "",
    "outbound_cnam": "",
    "dst_cnam": ""
}
```

Here is yours:

```
"0":{
    "calldate":"2013-08-14 11:41:28",
    "clid":"\"Ryan Merritt\" <1002>",
    "src":"1002",
    "dst":"8834404",
    "dcontext":"from-internal",
    "channel":"SIP\/1002-00000000",
    "dstchannel":"IAX2\/voipms-6749",
    "lastapp":"Dial",
    "lastdata":"IAX2\/voipms\/14798834404,300,",
    "duration":"7",
    "billsec":"0",
    "disposition":"NO ANSWER",
    "amaflags":"3",
    "accountcode":"",
    "uniqueid":"1376498488.1",
    "userfield":"",
    "did":"",
    "recordingfile":"",
    "cnum":"",
    "cnam":"",
    "outbound_cnum":"",
    "outbound_cnam":"",
    "dst_cnam":""},
"1":{
    "calldate":"2013-08-14 11:42:55",
    "clid":"\"Ryan Merritt\" <1002>",
    "src":"1002",
    "dst":"9187755592",
    "dcontext":"from-internal",
    "channel":"SIP\/1002-00000001",
    "dstchannel":"IAX2\/voipms-121",
    "lastapp":"Dial",
    "lastdata":"IAX2\/voipms\/19187755592,300,",
    "duration":"494",
    "billsec":"485",
    "disposition":"ANSWERED",
    "amaflags":"3",
    "accountcode":"",
    "uniqueid":"1376498575.3",
    "userfield":"",
    "did":"",
    "recordingfile":"",
    "cnum":"",
    "cnam":"",
    "outbound_cnum":"",
    "outbound_cnam":"",
    "dst_cnam":""
},
```

Notice how yours has the extra keys of "0" and "1."  I would try removing those and making your JSON from your PHP file look more like mine.

Comment: I get a response of the json and the datatable just sits at loading. No errors in the console.

Comment: @user1552172 Check your network panel in Chrome to see what response is from server.

Comment: The json from the php is coming back just like it was before but not in the table.

Comment: @user1552172 Remove all other parameters as shown in my Edit and see if it works.

Comment: @user1552172 Also, read this http://datatables.net/usage/server-side to make sure you are using it correctly.

Comment: @user1552172 Don't use their URL, use your own i.e. `'/php/connect/searchtablequery.php'`

Comment: ah ok my derpness, I am still getting a loading on the data in it.. json data is in the response from the network call.

Comment: @user1552172 Is your json file online for me to test?

Comment: It would be best if your PHP file that generates the JSON is on a server so I could test it.

Comment: pbx.wushuassistant.com username: testing password: test

Comment: You have a javascript error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` I am trying to get it working, one moment...

Comment: @user1552172 I can't test your page since I don't have access to your server but as per this jsfiddle, you can see how your data works using static JSON http://jsfiddle.net/HEDvf/667/

Comment: im curious on why it isnt pulling into the table then if the json is correct.

Comment: I think the json is being pulled from mysql but the mysql is being written and it is getting only half a record, evertime i jsonit it shows a new error with a record being half way written. I need to find a way to get database rows that are a few seconds behind so that the json has the proper ending syntax.

Comment: Open a new question with your (PHP) code that generates the JSON and show what you want it to look like and others (and maybe myself) will be able to help you.